# Angular uibDatePicker with JSON.NET and the inevitable time challenge

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, json, json.net, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want the user to enter dates, not times, just dates, using a datepicker. Doesn't seem too hard, but it's killing me.

I choose the 1st of December on the datepicker and click Save. In the Network tab on Chrome, I can see the data sent to the server has the value: `2015-11-30T22:00:00.000Z`

On the server, while debugging I can see the value in the Date field is `30/11/2015 22:00:00`.

This will then get stored in a `Date` column as `30 November 2015` and is wrong.

Where is the issue: the configuration of the angular directive, or the configuration of JSON.NET's deserialization? And how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously quite a common question, I just needed to search a bit better.

In the end I've implemented this directive, which modifies the model used by the datepicker:
https://gist.github.com/weberste/354a3f0a9ea58e0ea0de